# How can I replace bi-directional DirectedEdge pairs in a Graph with a single UndirectedEdge?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

The Cayley graphs produced by Mathematica 8.0's `CayleyGraph` function represent actions that are their own inverses in an unconventional way: rather than using a single edge without arrows, it uses two edges, each represented by an arrow.

Is there a way to replace all (and only) pairs of such reflexive arrows in a Cayley diagram with a single undirected edge, while leaving any unpaired directed edges untouched?

For example is there a way to make edges in this

```
CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4]]
```

[image]

look like this

[image]

---

Note that I'm aware that one could generate the desired output "manually", using `Graph` (as was done to generate the example above), but the solution I'm seeking must work for *far* more complex graphs than the one illustrated here from the simple group specifications that can be provided to `CayleyGraph`.

Comment: I suspect that the correct approach involves some searching (I'm not sure where) for matching pairs of `\[DirectedEdge]`, and then replacing (using `EdgeDelete` and `EdgeAdd`) those with a single `\[UndirectedEdge]` (somehow of the same color). But I have no idea how to do that. Alternately, in may be that a this requires a replacement for `CayleyGraph` that builds a graph from scratch (e.g., from some form of group specification or the output of `GroupGenerators` and `GroupElements`).

Comment: I just tried that, but got a message `Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported.` No idea what that means. I can't check the result right now (for running the front end over the internet I just don't have the necessary bandwidth, so I can only use the kernel right now). Anyway, here's my code: `Module[{vl=VertexList[#], el=EdgeList[#]},
       Graph[vl,
             el /. {x_ \[DirectedEdge] y_ /;
               el ~MemberQ~ (y \[DirectedEdge] x) :>
                 If[Order[x, y]==1,
                    x \[UndirectedEdge] y,
                    Unevaluated@Sequence[]]}]]&`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use custom `EdgeShapeFunction` as in

```
ClearAll[fromDirectedToMixedGraph]; 
fromDirectedToMixedGraph[g_Graph] :=  
   Module[{edges = (EdgeList[g]) //  DeleteDuplicates[#, Sort@#1 == Sort@#2 &] &,
   vertices = VertexList[g], vcoords = AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates], 
esf = EdgeShapeFunction -> (If[MemberQ[(Pick[
       EdgeList[g], (Count[EdgeList[g], # | Reverse[#]] > 1) & /@ 
        EdgeList[g], False]), #2 | Reverse[#2]], Arrow[#1], Line[#1]] &), options},
options = {First@# -> Select[Last@#, (MemberQ[edges, First@#] &)]} & /@ (Options[g]);
Graph[vertices, edges, vcoords, esf, options]]
```

Example:

```
Grid@Table[{g, fromDirectedToMixedGraph[g]}, {g, {CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4]], 
  CayleyGraph[AbelianGroup[{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]]}}]
```

[image]

EDIT: The following variant adds two options to control the rendering of multiple edges (as lines or bi-directional arrows). It also allows inheriting the options from the input graph and using any `Graph` option.

```
ClearAll[mixedEdgeGraph];
Options[mixedEdgeGraph] = Join[Options[Graph], 
         {"arrowSize" -> .03, "setBack" -> .1, "biDirectionalEdges" -> "line"}];

mixedEdgeGraph[g_Graph, opts : OptionsPattern[mixedEdgeGraph]] := 
 Module[{doubleEdges, singleEdges, vcoords, esf, options, 
 edges = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList[g], Sort@#1 == Sort@#2 &],vertices = VertexList[g]},
 {doubleEdges, singleEdges} =  DeleteDuplicates[#, Sort@#1 == Sort@#2 &] & /@ 
     (Pick[EdgeList[g], (MemberQ[EdgeList[g], Reverse[#]]) & /@ 
           EdgeList[g], #] & /@ {True, False});

(* remove from Options[g] properties and option values that belong to deleted edges *)
options = Sequence @@ DeleteCases[
 Options[g], (e_ -> __) /;  MemberQ[Complement[EdgeList[g], edges], e], {1, Infinity}];

(* default EdgeShapeFunction to render multi-edges as lines or bidirectional arrows*)
esf = If[FilterRules[{opts}, EdgeShapeFunction] =!= {}, 
         FilterRules[{opts}, EdgeShapeFunction], 
         EdgeShapeFunction -> (If[MemberQ[singleEdges, #2 |Reverse[#2]], 
         {Arrowheads[{{OptionValue["arrowSize"], 1}}], Arrow[#1, OptionValue["setBack"]]}, 
     {If[OptionValue["biDirectionalEdges"] =!= "line", 
        Arrowheads[{-OptionValue["arrowSize"], OptionValue["arrowSize"]}],
        Arrowheads[{{0., 1}}]], Arrow[#1, OptionValue["setBack"]]}] &)];

(* use vertex coordinates of g unless VertexCooordinates or GraphLayout is specified *)
vcoords =  If[FilterRules[{opts}, {GraphLayout}] =!= {}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> Automatic, AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]];

(* explictly provided Graph options override the default options inherited from g *)
Graph[vertices, edges, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]], vcoords, esf, options]]
```

Examples:

```
optns = Sequence @@ {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
                     VertexSize -> 0.4, ImageSize -> 300};
g1 = CayleyGraph[AbelianGroup[{2, 2, 2, 2}], optns];
g2 = CayleyGraph[AbelianGroup[{2, 2, 2}], optns];
g3 = CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[4], optns];
g4 = CayleyGraph[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]}], optns];
```

[image]

Additional examples:

```
g5 = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[7, 0.6], DirectedEdges -> True, 
          VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 300];
g6 = AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
                    {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}, 
        DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
        VertexSize -> 0.2,    ImageSize -> 300];
(PropertyValue[{g5, #}, EdgeStyle] = Hue[RandomReal[]]) & /@  EdgeList[g5];
(PropertyValue[{g6, #}, EdgeStyle] = Hue[RandomReal[]]) & /@  EdgeList[g6];
Grid[{#, mixedEdgeGraph[#], 
         mixedEdgeGraph[#, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
                         "biDirectionalEdges" -> "doublearrows"]} & /@ {g5, g6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'd also like to be able substitute colors, but I'm bot  sure how to modify the code above to do that. For example, I'd like to make all blue edges, say, magenta. I'd also like to rep ace the arrowhead style with something more like the one [shown here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/155297/12400).

Comment: @raxa ... Two ways to do that without changing the code: you can use something like: Define, (say, for the example graph `g2`) `newedgstyl = Options[g2, EdgeStyle] /. Hue[0.666666666666666] -> Hue[0.8]`, and then use it as `mixedEdgeGraph[SetProperty[g2, EdgeStyle -> newedgstyl[[1, 2]]]]`. Or, you can use it as `SetProperty[mixedEdgeGraph[g2], EdgeStyle -> newedgstyl[[1, 2]]]`.

Answer (score 9):

The previous answers are wonderful. But at the risk of being repetitive, here is another answer. I believe what you really desire is to replace multi-directed edges with bi-directed edges as well as identifying group elements via tooltips and distinguishing unity. For example:

```
CG[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]}], 3]
```

[image]

```
CG[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]}], 2]
```

[image]

In this fashion distractions are minimized. Here is the code:

```
mc[n : {___Integer}, func_List, list_List] := 
  Map[Fold[MapAt[#2[[1]], #1, List /@ #2[[2]]] &, #, 
     Transpose[{func, n}]] &, list];
mc[n : {___Integer}, func_, list_List] := 
  Map[MapAt[func, #, List /@ n] &, list];
mc[n_Integer, func_, list_List] := Map[MapAt[func, #, n] &, list];

formatCycles[c_Cycles] := 
  Row[Riffle[Row[Flatten@{"(", Riffle[#, " "], ")"}] & /@ c[[1]], 
    " "]];
formatCycles[c_] := 
  Row[Flatten[({"(", If[Length[#] > 1, Riffle[#, " "], #], ") "}) & /@
      c[[1]]]];
formatCycles[c_] := "" /; Sort[c] == c;
formatCycles[{}] := Style["(identity)", Gray];
formatCycles[Cycles[{}]] := Style["(identity)", Gray];
formatCycles[Cycles[{{}}]] := Style["(identity)", Gray];
$imageSize = 300;

CG[group_, dim_] := 
 Module[{v, e, edgeStyle, edgeColor, tools, eTool, vTool, ef, vf, 
   len, $CG, tooltips}, $CG = CayleyGraph[group];
  tooltips = AbsoluteOptions[$CG, Properties][[1, 2]];
  v = VertexList[$CG];
  len = Length[v];
  e = Rule @@@ EdgeList[$CG];
  edgeStyle = PropertyValue[$CG, {EdgeStyle}][[1, 2]];
  tools = 
   SplitBy[Sort[AbsoluteOptions[$CG, Properties][[1, 2]]], 
    Length[First[#]] &];
  (edgeColor[List @@ #1] = Lighter@#2[[1]]) & @@@ 
   mc[1, Rule @@ # &, edgeStyle];
  (vTool[First[#]] = formatCycles@Last[#][[1, 2]]) & /@ tools[[1]];
  (eTool[List @@ First[#]] = formatCycles@Last[#][[1, 2]]) & /@ 
   tools[[2]];
  If[len > 30, 
   If[dim == 2, 
    ef = ({edgeColor[#2], Arrowheads -> Medium, 
        Tooltip[Arrow[#1, 0.01], eTool[#2]]} &);
    vf = ({Lighting -> "Neutral", EdgeForm[Black], 
        RGBColor[0.696078431372549, 0.7588235294117647, 
         0.845098039215686], 
        Tooltip[If[
          len < 60, {Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]}, {Black, 
           Point[#]}], vTool[#2]]} &); 
    GraphPlot[e, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ef, 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> vf, ImageSize -> $imageSize, 
     ImageMargins -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> None, 
     MultiedgeStyle -> 0.001], 
    ef = ({edgeColor[#2], Arrowheads -> Small, 
        Tooltip[Arrow[#1], eTool[#2]]} &);
    vf = ({Lighting -> "Neutral", Specularity[Brown, 3], Brown, 
        Tooltip[If[
          len < 60, {Sphere[#, 0.05], Black, 
           Text[#2, #1]}, {Sphere[#, .1]}], vTool[#2]]} &); 
    GraphPlot3D[e, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ef, ViewAngle -> All, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> $imageSize, Boxed -> False, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0 ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
     MultiedgeStyle -> 0.001]], 
   If[dim == 2, 
    ef = ({edgeColor[#2], Arrowheads -> Medium, 
        Tooltip[Arrow[#1, 0.12], eTool[#2]]} &);
    vf = ({EdgeForm[{Black}], 
        If[#2 == 1, Blue, RGBColor[0.639216, 0.705882, 0.8]], 
        Tooltip[{Disk[#, 0.05]}, vTool[#2]]} &);
    GraphPlot[e, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ef, 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> vf, ImageSize -> $imageSize, 
     ImageMargins -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 10, 
     MultiedgeStyle -> 0.001], 
    ef = ({edgeColor[#2], Arrowheads -> Medium, 
        Tooltip[Arrow[#1], eTool[#2]]} &);
    vf = ({Lighting -> "Neutral", Specularity[Brown, 3], 
        If[#2 == 1, Hue[0.6], Gray], 
        Tooltip[If[len < 60, {Sphere[#, 0.1]}, {Point[#]}], 
         vTool[#2]]} &);
    GraphPlot3D[e, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ef, 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> vf, ImageSize -> $imageSize, 
     Boxed -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
     ImagePadding -> 0, MultiedgeStyle -> 0.001]]]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a complex Cayley graph:

```
g = CayleyGraph[AbelianGroup[{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]]
```

[image]

And here is its beautiful none-directed edge counterpart:

```
AdjacencyGraph[
    AdjacencyMatrix[g],
    AbsoluteOptions[g,VertexCoordinates],
    EdgeStyle->((EdgeStyle/.AbsoluteOptions[g,EdgeStyle])/.(x_\[DirectedEdge]y_)->
    (x\[UndirectedEdge]y)),
    DirectedEdges -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I get this to work for a graph in which some of the edges are directed (in which case I'd like to leave them alone)? E.g `g = CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4]]`?

Comment: The error I get for `DihedralGroup[4]` (or anything with single arrows between nodes) is *"VertexCoordinates->{...} at position 2 is not a non-empty square matrix"*. I get that error even if I substitute the coordinates for `AbelianGroup[{2, 2, 2}]` (which works on its own) when tying to use the code above for `DihedralGroup[4]`

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius AFAIK, you can't mix UE and DE in a `Graph` object...

Comment: @R.M: If that's so, is there way a to create what I'm looking for by superposing two graphs: one where all paired DE have been replaced with a UE while unpaired DE are made invisible, and another where the paired DE are made invisible, while the unpaired DE are left alone? (If that's the only way to accomplish what I'm looking for.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I updated the code with `DirectedEdges -> False` option so your problem is fixed now.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Thanks, that takes care of the error; but it seems to turn any DE into UE, when in fact they should remain DE.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I am not sure I understand your last comment. Wasn't your question: "Is there a way to replace all pairs of such reflexive arrows in a Cayley diagram with a single undirected edge?" - you said "undirected edge" and your diagram had only pairs. I think I answered that. If you have something else in mind you should probably post it as another question.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Sorry, I meant for the solution to apply to *any* Cayley graph, not just those for groups with all-UE. I've updated the question with a clarification and a more general example.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use both undirected and directed edges (i.e., mixed graph) in a `Graph` object. However, you can control the edge style and shapes for the multi-edge case separately and get what you want. Here's an example:

```
g = CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4]];

(* Separate the two sets of edges *)
edges1 = EdgeList@(g1 = EdgeDelete[g, DirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; EdgeQ[g, DirectedEdge[b, a]]]);
edges2 = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList[GraphDifference[g, g1]], #1 === Reverse[#2] &];

(* Style the two graphs and put them together *)
Graph[edges1~Join~edges2, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> {Thread[edges2 -> "Line"], Thread[edges1 -> "Arrow"]}~Flatten~1,
    EdgeStyle -> {Thread[edges2 -> Red], Thread[edges1 -> Blue]}~Flatten~1, 
    VertexStyle -> Black
]
```

[image]

Comment: you can also do the stylings and shape in one go with a more detailed edge shape function. Note that the graph is still a directed one... `DirectedGraphQ[finalgraph]` will give `True`

Comment: This works great except for groups without DE (e.g. `AbelianGroup[{2, 2}]`), where it gives weird results.

Comment: It gives the correct result, but the orientation is wonky, because `Graph` uses an automatic layout that's dependent on the order in which edges are input. You can force it to be something that's useful with `GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"`, or anything else you like. The alternate is to explicitly provide `VertexCoordinates`...

Answer (score 2):

Version 10 supports graphs with mixed directed and undirected edges.

```
g = CayleyGraph[DihedralGroup[4]]

newEdges = Flatten[
  GatherBy[EdgeList[g], Sort] /. {{a_  \[DirectedEdge] b_, _} :> {a <-> b}}
]

e = GroupBy[newEdges, Head]

g2 = Graph[newEdges, EdgeStyle -> Catenate[Thread /@ {e[UndirectedEdge] -> Red, e[DirectedEdge] -> Blue}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Since Wolfram apparently has its own definition of "Launched" (which elsewhere on Earth means "immediately available", at least to highly paying "Premier" — another word for which Wolfram has its own definition — customers), I don't have access to this yet.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I got a new license key in email (my university has a site license), but not a download link.  I downloaded the trial version installer (which is said to be identical to the full version installer) and used it with the full version license key.

Comment: Yes, I've been told they're sending out the e-mails in "waves". They just forgot that the "launch" announcement really ought to come after the last wave (at least to "Premier" customers).