# Labeled and Graph don't mix?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

In an attempt to create a legend for a graph drawing, I find that Labeled only works without the position options (except for `Center`).

```
   Graph[Range[2], {
  Labeled[DirectedEdge[1, 2], "BEFORE"]}]
```

[image]

But

```
Graph[Range[2], {
  Labeled[DirectedEdge[1, 2], "BEFORE", Bottom]}]
```

[image]

Similarly for the other `Labeled` position options like `Top`, `Left`, `Right`.

Also, adding ImagePadding doens't help. I've tried some - but not all - `Labeled`'s other options:

```
{Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, Background -> None, 
 BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 DefaultBaseStyle -> "Labeled", DefaultLabelStyle -> "LabeledLabel", 
 Editable -> Automatic, Frame -> None, FrameMargins -> 0, 
 FrameStyle -> Automatic, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> {}, RotateLabel -> False, RoundingRadius -> 0, 
 Selectable -> Automatic, Spacings -> Automatic, 
 SyntaxForm -> Automatic}
```

Known issue?

Comment: I think that with `Bottom` the label falls below the plot area and thus does not show... try setting the option `PlotRange` to show a larger vertical area.

Answer (score 5):

I do not see any advantage of using `Labeled` vs intended for graphs `EdgeLabels`. Here is an aap to demonstrate arbitrary label placement:

```
Manipulate[Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 
  Placed[Style["OVERLAP", Red, 15], {a, p}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.5}, {-.15, .15}}, EdgeShapeFunction -> esf],
  {{esf, "Arrow", "Arrowheads"}, {"Line", "Arrow"}},
  {{p, {.5, .7}, "scaled position\nin the label"}, {-2, 0}, {3, 1.5}}, 
  {{a, .5, "scaled position of\nthe label along edge"}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: that's an option but my intention is to build legends for graphs, using `Row`, `Column`, `Grid`. In any case, something is broken in `Labeled`-`Graph` interaction.

Comment: @alancalvitti Can you show how you intend to use `Row`, etc. for this?

Comment: for example: `Column[{
  Column[{"OVERLAP", 
    Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Red]}, ImageSize -> 150]}, 
   Center, -0.5],
  Column[{"BEFORE", 
    Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Blue]}, ImageSize -> 150]}, 
   Center, -0.5],
  Column[{"AFTER", 
    Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Green]}, ImageSize -> 150]}, 
   Center, -0.5]
  }]`

Comment: I suppose all this can be done within `Graph` by specifying vertex positions, but I prefer not specifying all these small details.

Comment: By the way, this is a separate Q but shouldn't I be able to remove the arrowheads w/ `Arrowheads`? Ie,  `Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Red, Arrowheads[0]]` but that doesn't do it.

Comment: @alancalvitti for removing arrowheads - why not to use just `UndirectedEdge` ?

Comment: @alancalvitti It is possible with `EdgeShapeFunction`. But generally for removing arrowheads - why not to use just UndirectedEdge ?

Comment: Nice! To round it into an awesome app, you could have an input field to enter the label and operate only on the selected edge.

Comment: Re arrowheads - because this problem (TimeML markup) results in hybrid Directed and UndirectedEdges, which Graph does not support, though there's code here but it's not transparent: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/how-can-i-replace-bi-directional-directededge-pairs-in-a-graph-with-a-single-und

Comment: @alancalvitti I added code showing how to control arrowheads ON/OFF .

Comment: @R.M Thanks! Yes, if I find some time ;)

Comment: Nice (+1). `Graph[{Labeled[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Placed["label", {a, p}]]}]` also works.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov,+1 but cannot accept. The issue is the orthogonality of the language. Why don't *all* `Labeled` options work with `Graph`?