# Automatically convert pairs of directed edges to an undirected edge?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a directed graph, which for some pairs of vertices, has a directed edge between them in each direction. I would like to replace such pairs of directed edges between the same vertices but in opposite directions, by a single undirected edge. What's a simple way to do this?

Comment: Including a sample graph would increase the speed and likelihood of answers.

Comment: related Q/A: [How can I replace bi-directional DirectedEdge pairs in a Graph with a single UndirectedEdge?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6282/125)

Comment: @kguler From the title and a *quick* glance that seems like a duplicate.  Is it not?

Comment: @kguler I see that the Accepted answer using `EdgeShapeFunction` so it is more formatting that actual replacement.  I guess not a duplicate after all?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, the two questions are "almost" the same. However, because version 10 allows mixed graphs and version 9 did not, making explicit the requirement that the output is a _mixed graph_ will make the current question truly different from the linked one.

Comment: Related: [(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/121)

Answer (score 4):

A brute-force method using [`Gather`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gather.html).

Starting graph:

```
SeedRandom[0]
edges = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {12, 2}]

Graph[edges]
```

[image]

Processing and new graph (this will work with both [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) and [`DirectedEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedEdge.html):

```
new = 
  Gather[edges, #[[1]] == #2[[2]] && #[[2]] == #2[[1]] &] /.
    {{_[a_, b_], __} :> a <-> b, {x_} :> x};

Graph[new]
```

[image]

### Update

Seeking a more efficient implementation, if:

- All edges in the original graph are either `Rule` or `UndirectedEdge` at the outset
- You do not mind losing multiple (directed) edges between vertices

I believe we can use the much more efficient [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) as follows:

```
new2 =
  Union /@ GatherBy[edges, Sort] /.
    {{_[a_, b_], __} :> a <-> b, {x_} :> x};

Graph[new2]
```

[image]

Comment: One mistake everyone has made in all the answers is that `Graph[EdgeList[g]]` will lose unconnected vertices.  `Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g]]` will keep them.  This is *not* nitpicking.  I've been bitten hard by this mistake.  I know that you are constructing the example graph based purely on an edge list, but this is something that's still worth paying attention to ...

Comment: Would you clarify how `/. {{_[a_, b_], __} :> a <-> b, {x_} :> x}` works?  I don't fully understand `_[a_, b_]` but it seems to be an opaque variation of belisarius'  `Rule[a_,b_]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the caveat.

Comment: @David `_[a_, b_]` is a pattern for an expression with any head and two arguments, therefore it will match `Rule`, `DirectedEdge`, `UndirectedEdge`, etc.  This lets me collapse any of the sublists from `Gather` into a single `UndirectedEdge` without worrying about type.  `{x_} :> x` strips the `List` from any singlets.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to use `GatherBy`

```
bidirectedToUndirected=Join@@(GatherBy[EdgeList@#,Union] /. {x_, y_} :> {UndirectedEdge @@ x}) &;
```

Example (from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html)):

```
words = DictionaryLookup["wol*"];
edges = Flatten[Map[(Thread[# ->  DeleteCases[Nearest[words, #, 3], #]]) &, words]];
opts = {VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 60, ImageSize -> 500};
g = Graph[edges, opts];

Row[{g, Graph[VertexList[g], bidirectedToUndirected@g, opts]}]  (* thanks: @Szabolcs  *)
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, right. I missed the _mixed graph_ requirement (which version 9 does not support except through using different `EdgeShapeFunction` properties for different edge types as in the linked Q/A).

Comment: Bloody hell, where did *that* come from? ;-p  (I didn't see `GatherBy` until *after* posting my version.)  +1 of course. \*sigh\*

Comment: +1 for using `Union` instead of `Sort` and `Union`

Comment: @David Out of curiosity are you comparing that to my answer?  I have reason for what I wrote, or at least I think I do.

Comment: Mr.Wizard You are indeed perceptive. Yes, I was.

Answer (score 2):

One can do it quite fast with `AdjacencyMatrix`

```
graphSum[graphs__, opts___?OptionQ] /; VectorQ[{graphs}, GraphQ] :=
  Graph[Union @@ VertexList /@ {graphs}, Join @@ EdgeList /@ {graphs}, opts];

pairwiseMin[a_, b_, dom_: Reals] := 
  If[dom === Integers, Quotient, Divide][a + b - Abs[a - b], 2];

mixedGraph[g_Graph] := graphSum @@ Map[AdjacencyGraph[VertexList@g, #] &, {# - #2, #2}] &[#,
     pairwiseMin[#, Transpose@#, Integers]] &@AdjacencyMatrix@g
```

Here `graphSum` is analog of `GraphSum` which was in old `Combinatorica` package. There is built-in `` GraphComputation`GraphSum `` in V10, but it doesn't work for mixed graphs (one can fix it, see the [previous revision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/73815/3) of this answer).

```
SeedRandom[0]
edges = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {12, 2}];
g = Graph[Range@7, edges]
```

[image]

```
mixedGraph@g
```

[image]

It also converts directed loops to undirected loops, but they have the same meaning.

Timing for a big graph:

```
SeedRandom[0]
edges = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {20000, 2}];
g = Graph[edges];
mixedGraph@g; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.213162, Null} *)
```

It is comparable with Mr.Wizards `new2` but it takes into account multiple edges.

---

Also one can do it purely with graph functions

```
mixedGraph[g_Graph] := 
 GraphUnion[GraphDifference@##, UndirectedGraph@GraphIntersection@##] &[g, ReverseGraph@g]
```

However, it is slow and simplifies multiple edges.

Comment: +1 for use of some interesting functions, but at least in my testing this is several times slower than my naive brute-force method.  I don't know if your output should be considered better or worse than mine; I purposely wanted to change the graph as little as possible but that may not be important to the OP.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is not fine, I change the wording a bit. Also I add another approach with graph functions which works fine with multigraphs

Answer (score 1):

Another not-efficient alternative:

```
edges //. {a___, Rule[x_, y_], b___, Rule[y_, x_], c___} :> {a, b, c, UndirectedEdge[x, y]}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's going to be significantly worse than `Gather`, based on earlier experimentation with multiple `___` patterns.  I'll be happy to be proven wrong but until then I'm holding my vote as an edge list may be quite long.

Comment: Seems I was wrong.  The speed of this function depends greatly on the nature of the edge list.  With little duplication it can be slightly faster than mine, but with more duplication it can be an order of magnitude slower.  +1 for a pretty implementation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As almost always, a repeated replacement rule can't beat a clever implementation in the general case. Thanks for your comments/experimentation.