# Graph equivalent of GraphPlot's MultiEdge style?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I like the default display of `Graph` much better than that of `GraphPlot`, but I do not see how to turn off the use of multi-edges in a directed graph.  (That is, if `{a,b}` and `{b,a}` are edges, I would like one line between them that has two arrowheads.)  Is it possible?

Related: is it not odd that `GraphPlot[Graph[...]]` produces a different display than `Graph[...]`?  If there is no way to turn off multi-edges in `Graph`, one might hope to simply `GraphPlot[Graph[...],MultiedgeStyle->False]` and get the same style except without multi-edges.

Comment: You could use the `SimpleGraph` function to get rid of multi-edges before plotting. This will also remove self-loops which may be undesirable ...

Comment: It's a directed graph.  I want the self loops.  I want a reciprocal relation to be one double-ended arrow instead of two separate arrows.  Simple example: how to replace the multi-edge with a since edge (with two arrow heads) for `Graph[{a -> a, a -> b, b -> a, c -> c}]`.

Comment: "I want a reciprocal relation to be one double-ended arrow instead of two separate arrows." <- That's not exactly the same thing that you described in the question.  Can you update your post?

Comment: @Szabolcs Done.  Actually I left that out because I did not realize Graph produced multi-edges for undirected graphs.  I see now that it does.

Comment: If you're only interested in directed graphs, but not multigraphs, then take a look at the example [in the question I asked yesterday](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95848/how-to-use-the-edgelayout-suboption-of-graphlayout).  Using `"EdgeLayout" -> "StraightLine"` might work ... But don't try it for multigraphs.  When I did, it hung my kernel for good.

Comment: @Szabolcs That provides an answer to my question.  I'll gladly accept it if you move it to an answer.

Comment: closely related Q/A: [How can I replace bi-directional DirectedEdge pairs in a Graph with a single UndirectedEdge?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6282/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "MultiEdgeDistance"

In versions 13.+ (perhaps in earlier versions too) using the option

```
 GraphLayout -> {"MultiEdgeDistance" -> 0}
```

gives the desired result:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultiEdgeDistance" -> 0}]
```

[image]

#### "SelfLoopRadius"

There is also the suboption  `"SelfLoopRadius"` to control rendering of self-loops:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"SelfLoopRadius" -> 0}]
```

[image]

Further examples:

```
Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & @  Table[
 Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 3, 3 -> 3},
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> {"MultiEdgeDistance" -> d, "SelfLoopRadius" -> r}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
     Style[Column[{"MultiEdgeDistance" -> d, "SelfLoopRadius" -> r}], 14]], 
 {r, Subdivide[3]}, {d, Subdivide[3]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ***if {a,b} and {b,a} are edges, I would like one line between them that has two arrowheads***

```
ClearAll[modiFy]
modiFy[as_ : {-.05, .05}] := Graph[DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList@#, Sort @ # == Sort @ #2 &], 
 EdgeStyle -> {e : DirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; a =!= b && MemberQ[EdgeList@#, Reverse @ e] :> 
   Arrowheads[as]}, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[#], Options @ #]&
```

**Examples:**

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}]
```

[image]

```
modiFy[] @ g1
```

[image]

```
modiFy[{-.08, .05}] @ g1
```

[image]

```
g2 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}, ImageSize -> 400,
  EdgeLabels -> Placed["Name", 1/3], ImagePadding -> 20,  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
modiFy[] @ g2
```

[image]